# Unresolved dependency error when creating a new project

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

This error appears when creating a new Android Application module in Android Studio using Fixed Tabs + Swipes for navigation.

It says:

> The following dependencies were not resolvable. See your build.gradle
>   file for details. - com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.0

[image: The error]

I'm targeting Android 4.0+ devices. Why is the compatibility library involved? [One workaround](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2453173) is to install this library using the Android SDK manager, but I'm concerned my app will actually *use* this compatibility library when there is no reason to. The ActionBar and fixed tab navigation should be built-in to the Android 4.0+ framework right?

Comment: Can you post your manifest file?

Comment: Can you post also build.gradle and your gradle version (check /gradle/gradle-wrapper.properties inside your project) ?

Comment: Whichever the version you are targeting... Compat may be here because of the minVersion of your project (Check your manifest)

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me with IntelliJ Idea 13 Ultimate when creating new Gradle Module. I was working on the app that supports Froyo. I had to manually add support libraries to the SDK. After that I was able to build just fine. Here is the screenshot of Project Structure settings for SDK that I have:

[image]

As you can see, support for v4, v7 and v13 which were added manually. Those will be associated with Android API 19 Platform (in my case). When you create next new Gradle Module, you will still need to go to Project Structure to select the SDK under Project, but you will not need to add support libs again. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I installed the compatibility library anyways. Something I didn't realize is that you can't create your first module by using `File -> New Module`. You have to use `File -> Project Structure -> New Module` for your first module. It's really unintuitive. After I did this, then everything worked.